# Android view exceeds its parent layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridlayout

Im trying to define a 2 lines "range" view, such as `"from ___"\n"to ___"`
I decided that its best to use the gridLayout, since I wanted both editText views to start and end at the same locations.
Here's the xml definition:

```
<GridLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:rowCount="2"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:id="@+id/rangeLayout">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="From"
            android:id="@+id/fromLabel"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/>

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:editable="true"
            android:numeric="integer|decimal" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:text="To"
            android:id="@+id/textView3" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:id="@+id/editText2"
            android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
            android:numeric="integer|decimal" />

    </GridLayout>
```

I dont see what I did wrong, but both editText steps over the gridLayout, so actually its right end isnt visible to the user.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

After initialization in runtime the indexing of the grid cells will be lost.

- Assign a column and and row to your grid views:

  android:layout_row="some integer" |
  android:layout_column="some integer"
- Use a span property in order to span over columns\rows

  android:layout_rowSpan="some integer" |
  android:layout_columnSpan="some integer"

Comment: I had those values before, But i didnt see any imorovement with those in place so I neglected it from my question

Comment: so can you clarify your question

Comment: Even with your suggested solution, The right end of the edit texts exceed the borders of the gridLayout, thus practically invisible since my layout is drawn on the entire width

Comment: Try replacing the the android:layout_width="wrap_content" -> with arbitrary number - android:layout_width="1dp". also add the column and row  indexing plus a span as i suggested, this should solve your issue

Comment: Using a fixed value in layout_width forces itself over span. it doesnt work. any other ideas?

Comment: it works for me,did you try it? what version are you running?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54820/discussion-between-shaydel-and-e-r-a-n).